# How to make created packages available on make menuconfig?

Tags: makefile, openwrt

I'm trying to create a libxerces package for OpenWrt. Following the instructions from this site http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages, I created a folder called libxerces-c inside the packages directory and a simple Makefile to have the package listed on make menuconfig, but it's not happening.

The Makefile is defined as the following:

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2006-2013 OpenWrt.org
#
# This is free software, licensed under the GNU General Public License v2.
# See /LICENSE for more information.
#

include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

# Name and release number of this package
PKG_NAME:=xerces-c
PKG_VERSION:=3.1.1
PKG_RELEASE:=1

PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)
PKG_SOURCE:=$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=http://apache.mirror.pop-sc.rnp.br/apache//xerces/c/3/sources/
PKG_CAT:=zcat

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

# Specify package information for this program. 
# The variables defined here should be self explanatory.
define Package/libxerces
  SECTION:=libs
  CATEGORY:=Libraries
  TITLE:=Validating XML parser written in a portable subset of C++.
  URL:=http://xerces.apache.org/
endef

define Package/libxerces/description
  Xerces-C++ is a validating XML parser written in a portable subset of
  C++.  Xerces-C++ makes it easy to give your application the ability
  to read and write XML data. A shared library is provided for parsing,
  generating, manipulating, and validating XML documents. Xerces-C++ is
  faithful to the XML 1.0 recommendation and associated standards (DOM
  1.0, DOM 2.0, SAX 1.0, SAX 2.0, Namespaces, XML Schema Part 1 and
  Part 2).  It also provides experimental implementations of XML 1.1
  and DOM Level 3.0.  The parser provides high performance, modularity,
  and scalability.
endef     

CONFIGURE_ARGS+= --host=mips-openwrt-linux

define Build/Configure
  $(call Build/Configure/Default)    
endef

define Build/Compile
  $(call Build/Compile/Default)
endef

define Package/libxerces/install
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,libxerces))
```

I already tried to execute the install script

```
./scripts/feeds install libxerces-c
```

But nothing happened. I still can't see the package after executing make menuconfig.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. add the *feed* with the package to your `feeds.conf.default` or create a `feeds.conf`
2. then `./scripts/feeds update -a` (update all feeds... you could just set the feed's name instead of using `-a`)
3. then `./scripts/feeds install foobar`

[...]

... You obviously called install on `libxerces-c` while your package is called `libxerces`?

Comment: You can also simply add a folder with your Makefile in the $buildroot/packages/ dir.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not still searching for it but here is the answer.
For your package to appear in the menuconfig TUI you need to add the following 
option to you Makefile inside the define Package clause:

```
MENU:1
```

Thus this part of your Makefile will look like:

```
define Package/libxerces
SECTION:=libs
  CATEGORY:=Libraries
  TITLE:=Validating XML parser written in a portable subset of C++.
  URL:=http://xerces.apache.org/
endef
```

Answer (score 0):

can you do a `make menuconfig`, and see if any error message about your package 'libxerces' is shown. My setup for custom packages is something like:

```
mkdir package/custom
mkdir package/custom/
ln -s /path/to/package/libxerces/ package/custom/
```

If your makefile is correct, then Libraries->libxerces should appear in menuconfig, if not an error message *should* be printed on make/make menuconfig. You will be able to do `make package/libxerces/compile` etc. also. Note: your package name is libxerces not libxerces-c.